# Slick Grid - Examples?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, grid, slickgrid

I have been perusing examples of slick grid and wanted to ping the SO community and inquire examples of excel spreadsheet editing demo's? As far as storage the grid is just going to store integers of data and the grid will be hosted within an mvc3 razor page.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at spreadsheet example provided by the developer(s)? http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html

Comment: Hi, I have actually.  This one is the most appealing (http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html).  However, I'm just not sure how to hook it up to a data model (mvc3) and iterate and save the values, etc,.

Comment: @Jacquo just use your skills!